# Python: defining properties in constructor from a list of items

Tags: python, class, properties

I would like to declare properties in the constructor of my class.

The class MaterialOne shows how I have it currently. Every property has to be defined separately. However, I will have groups of similar properties, which I would like to give the same fset/fget/fdel.

Since it requires a lot of code to write all the properties explicit, I would like to define the properties in a more concise way. I therefore thought of letting the constructor handle this. Class MateralTwo shows how I have that in mind.

Unfortunately it doesn't work, as I get TypeErrors:

```
TypeError: get_property() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

I can understand why it complains, but I can't think of any solution. I don't necessarily want to define the properties from a list in the constructor. What I am looking for is a more concise and clean method of defining them.

```
class MaterialOne(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass;

    def del_property(attr):
        """Abstract deller"""
        def del_attr(self):
            setattr(self, attr, None);
        return del_attr

    def set_property(attr):
        """Abstract setter."""
        def set_attr(self, x):
            setattr(self, attr, x);            
        return set_attr

    def get_property(attr):
        """Abstract getter"""
        def get_attr(self):
            if getattr(self, attr) is not None:
                return getattr(self, attr); 
            else:
                return 'Some calculated value..'
        return get_attr

    _young = None;
    _shear = None;
    _poisson = None;

    young = property(fget=get_property('_young'), fset=set_property('_young'), fdel=del_property('_young'));
    shear = property(fget=get_property('_shear'), fset=set_property('_shear'), fdel=del_property('_shear'));
    poisson = property(fget=get_property('_poisson'), fset=set_property('_poisson'), fdel=del_property('_poisson'));


class MaterialTwo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        properties = ['young', 'shear', 'poisson'];
        self.create_properties(properties)

    def del_property(attr):
        """Abstract deller"""
        def del_attr(self):
            setattr(self, attr, None);
        return del_attr

    def set_property(attr):
        """Abstract setter."""
        def set_attr(self, x):
            setattr(self, attr, x);            
        return set_attr

    def get_property(attr):
        """Abstract getter"""
        def get_attr(self):
            if getattr(self, attr) is not None:
                return getattr(self, attr); 
            else:
                return 'Some calculated value..'
        return get_attr        

    def create_properties(self, items):
        for item in items:
            storage = '_'+item;
            setattr(self, storage, None);
            setattr(self, item, property(fget=self.get_property(storage), fset=self.set_property(storage), fdel=self.del_property(storage)));


steel = MaterialOne(); 
steel.young = 2e11;
steel.poisson = 0.3;
print steel.poisson
print steel.shear

carbon = MaterialTwo();
carbon.young = 2e11;
carbon.poisson = 0.3;
print carbon.poisson
print carbon.shear
```

To clarify some more on the code. What I would like to write are Classes for materials,  Solid, Liquid, Gas, each of them a subclass of Material. Many material properties will just be assigned. Some can be calculated based on which have been defined. Given two elastic moduli a third can be calculated for instance.

This I have implemented now using something quite similar as MaterialOne. However, as I am getting more material properties, and will also include more of these kind of calculations, I would like to make it cleaner, more organized. Writing it as I did in MaterialTwo is a possibility to me.

Comment: style points unrelated to your problem: you don't need semicolons in python

Comment: What, ultimately, are you trying to accomplish? (It looks like you might be headed down the wrong path.) Are you perhaps trying to calculate each value "on demand" when the property is first accessed and then cache the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> setattr(self, item, property(...
> ```

This is ultimately your problem. Since properties are **descriptors**, they must be bound to the class, not the instance. You will need to [override `__getattr__()`, `__setattr__()`, and `__delattr__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access) and implement it there.

Comment: Exactly, it comes down to that line. And like you said, the descriptor is bound to the class and not the instance. It therefore won't work from the constructor. I understand now. I'll see what overriding will involve, but likely I'll have to revert to how I did in MaterialOne.

Answer (score 0):

All definitions should have `self` as the first argument.

This is how these functions should be:

```
def del_property(self, attr):
def sel_property(self, attr):
def get_property(self, attr):
```

Answer (score -1):

When methods are called on an object in Python, the object is silently passed as the first argument, which is why you're getting an error saying you're passing in too many arguments. As other people said, you need to include self as the first parameter to your functions.